# Selection of languages - only last langiage shown

Tags: selected

When I select f.e. 2 languages: 'en' and 'de' in the respective checkboxes
the 2 results are shown on screen

'en' and 'de'

but in the 4 'if' requests it only selects the last 'on_screen_language_for_print_de'
and not the first 'on_screen_language_for_print_en'

```
    foreach($_POST['language_for_print'] as $seleccion) {
    echo "<p>".$seleccion ."</p>";


            if (!empty($seleccion=='en')){
                $on_screen_language_for_print_en="yes" ; 
                } else {
                $on_screen_language_for_print_en="" ; 
                }

            if (!empty($seleccion=="es")){
                $on_screen_language_for_print_es="yes"; 
                 } else {  
                $on_screen_language_for_print_es="" ; 
                }

            if (!empty($seleccion=="fr")){
                $on_screen_language_for_print_fr="yes";  
                } else {            
                $on_screen_language_for_print_fr="" ; 
                }

            if (!empty($seleccion=="de")){
                $on_screen_language_for_print_de="yes";  
                } else {            
                $on_screen_language_for_print_de="" ; 
                } 
       }
```

Thank you very much for having a look.
Manfred

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution:

```
foreach($_POST['language_for_print'] as $seleccion) {
    echo "<p>".$seleccion ."</p>";
        //create array with country code
        $myArray[]=$seleccion;
        //print_r($myArray);
       
            if (in_array("en", $myArray, true)) {
                $on_screen_language_for_print_en="yes" ;
                } else {
                $on_screen_language_for_print_en="" ;
                }

            if (in_array("es", $myArray, true)) {
                $on_screen_language_for_print_es="yes";
                 } else {  
                $on_screen_language_for_print_es="" ;
                }

            if (in_array("fr", $myArray, true)) {
                $on_screen_language_for_print_fr="yes";  
                } else {            
                $on_screen_language_for_print_fr="" ;
                }

            if (in_array("de", $myArray, true)) {
                $on_screen_language_for_print_de="yes";  
                } else {            
                $on_screen_language_for_print_de="" ;
                }
           
    }
```